# mp4 video is not playing in mobile app

Tags: php, android, html

Why the problem occur and how to detect the video is supported or not support?

I think video screen size is may problem but not sure. Pls help me How to detect mp4 vidoe portion has used unsupported format. How to resolve it.

mp4video is not playing in mobile recorded from a browser/

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all you will want to make sure your browser is compatible with your code. Most browsers only support some html and not most.
If you need to know if it is compatible or or there is a very helpful tool on 
W3 schools, just type whatever you are looking for to change in the search bar and scroll down it will say If it is or not compatible with the browser.

If that's not it, then you need to update your flash player or whatever player android uses/Quicktime maybe?idk lol. Anyway if thats not it check your code you probably didn't write something write
hope this helps!